# Iterating through two lists that contain dictionaries, appending matches to a third list

Tags: python, dictionary, match

I have two lists that contain dictionaries:

```
list105 = [
{'Country': 'Zimbabwe', 'GDP/Pop 2005': 281.0751453319367}
{'Country': 'Zambia', 'GDP/Pop 2005': 654.055392253311}
{'Country': 'Congo (Dem. Rep.)', 'GDP/Pop 2005': 115.37122637190915}
]

list202 = [
{'Country': 'Vietnam', 'GDP/Pop 2002': 633.4709249146734}
{'Country': 'Zambia', 'GDP/Pop 2002': 1198.4556066429468}
{'Country': 'Vanuatu', 'GDP/Pop 2002': 1788.4344216880352}
]
```

Is it possible to iterate through both lists of dictionaries, match the 'Country' key, and append all unique keys from either dictionary to a new dictionary created in the third list?E.g. following from above, the third list would contain:

```
list2and3 = [
{'Country': 'Zambia', 'GDP/Pop 2005': 654.055392253311, 'GDP/Pop 2002': 1198.4556066429468}
]
```

I've started off with something like:

```
list2and3 = []
for line in list105:
    for row in list202:
        if line['Country'] == row['Country']:
            #do something and append to list2and3
```

Comment: Do both common dicts happen to be at the same index? Or is it just for this example

Comment: Wouldn't a data structure like `list2and3 = [{'Country': 'Zambia', 'GDP/Pop': {'2002': 1198.4556066429468, '2005': 654.055392253311}}]` make more sense? It would be much easier to populate this structure.

Comment: Your input isn't well normalized. What haven't you shown us from your real dataset? Or would `list105 = [('Zimbabwe', '281...'), ...]` or even `{'Zimbabwe': '281...'}` be a much better representation?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the first list to a dict:

```
d = {x['Country']:x for x in list105}
```

Then iterate the second list and add data to the dict:

```
for item in list202:
    key = item['Country']
    if key in d:
        d[key].update(item)
    else:
        d[key] = item
```

Finally, apply `.values()` to convert the dict back to a list:

```
newlist = d.values()
```

Note: this data structure is sub-optimal, consider rethinking it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from copy import deepcopy
list2and3 = []
for line in list105:
    for row in list202:
        if line['Country'] == row['Country']:
            dic = deepcopy(line) # creates a deepcopy of row, so that the
            dic.update(row)      # update operation doesn't affects the original object
            list2and3.append(dic)

print list2and3
```

**output:**

```
[{'Country': 'Zambia', 'GDP/Pop 2005': 654.055392253311, 'GDP/Pop 2002': 1198.4556066429468}]
```

Comment: this approach might take a long time since you loop inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may want a better solution without loop.

```
[x for x in list105 for y in list202 if x['Country'] == y['Country'] and x != y and not x.update(y)]
```

1 list comprehesion can lead you to the answer but it may be not human-friendly. Just choose what you like.